# Is this many-to-many relationship possible in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, many-to-many, polymorphic-associations

I'm trying to get my head around using polymorphic relationships for a many-to-many relationship between `suppliers` and `products`:

```
products
  id
  name
suppliers
  id
  name

product_supplier
  id
  product_id        // belongsToMany easily takes care of this id
  supplier_id       // and this id
  price             // this can be fetched using withPivot('price')
  deliverymethod_id // I'm having difficulties "joining" this one.
```

I'm confident in using `belongsToMany()`, I can easily do something like this:

```
public function products()
{
    return $this
    ->belongsToMany('Supplier')
    ->withPivot('price');
}
```

But the catch here is joining to that third column in the relationship table:

```
deliverymethods
  id
  name
```

I am unsure how to do this. I've been told that Polymorphic Relationships are what I'm after however I'm unsure how to implement them for my situation.

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations

According to the documentation, I would have to rename my table columns to include `*able_id` and `*able_type`. This is really confusing.

I was expecting laravel to having something like `belongsToMany('Supplier')->withAlso('Deliverymethod')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid that method does not exist (yet?).

What I fall back to is manually filling in the 3rd relation:

```
public function products()
{
    return $this
    ->belongsToMany('Supplier')
    ->withPivot('price', 'delivermethod_id');
}
```

Now I can access `->pivot->deliverymethod_id` on every `Product` that I get via `Supplier`.

You could even add a function in your `Product` model that fills this in automatically:

```
Class Product ... {

protected $appends = array('deliverymethod');

public function getDeliverymethodAttribute()
{
    return Deliverymethod::find($this->pivot->delivermethod_id);
}
```

Now every time you request a product via it's relation to the supplier, it *automatically* includes a `deliverymethod` attribute with the object in it.

(To have it not throw an error when you get a `Product` directly, just remove the `$appends` variable from the `Product` model and call the `getDeliverymethodAttribute()` method manually whenever you need it.)

### Short explanation about polymorphic relations:

Polymorphic relations are for relations, where two models are related to a third model at the same time. So for example both a `User` and a `Product` can have a `Picture` of them. Now, it doesn't make sense to have two models for the pictures (`UserPicture` and `ProductPicture`), since they both have the same characteristics. This would be a perfect reason to use a polymorphic relation, where the `Picture` can both belong to a `User` **or** a `Product`.

However, in your case the `Deliverymethod` applies *directly to the relation* between `Supplier` and `Product`. So this is not where polymorphic relations would work, but it has instead to be done the way you did it.